# Cannot use fluent html lambda expressions in Spark view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, spark-view-engine, fluenthtml

I'm attempting to use fluent html and the spark view engine in my asp.net mvc application.
I've assinged the proper base class, added the assemblies, and when i do this.TextBox("MyProperty") it works fine.
However I get the below exception when i attempt to use this.TextBox(m=>m.MyProperty). 
Any idea what can be causing this?

Exception:

```
Dynamic view compilation failed.
c:\Users\Midas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008    \Projects\ChurchMVC\ChurchMVC\Views\Poll\New.spark(6,31): error CS1660: Cannot convert     lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
c:\Users\Midas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008    \Projects\ChurchMVC\ChurchMVC\Views\Poll\New.spark(7,28): error CS1660: Cannot convert     lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

1 using MvcContrib.FluentHtml;
2 using System;
3 using System.Collections.Generic;
4 using System.Linq;
5 using System.Web.Mvc;
6 using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
7 using Microsoft.Web.Mvc;
8 using MvcContrib.FluentHtml.Elements;
9 
10 namespace ChurchMVC.Controllers
11 {
12 
13 [global::Spark.SparkViewAttribute(
14     TargetNamespace="ChurchMVC.Controllers",
15     Templates = new string[] {
16       "Poll\\New.spark",
17       "Layouts\\Application.spark",
18       "Layouts\\TwoColumn.spark",
19       "Layouts\\Base.spark"
20     })]
21 public class View6dda34d85cf14f8d8946e77056f25819 :     Spark.Web.Mvc.SparkView<ChurchMVC.Models.ViewModels.PollViewModel>
22 {
23 
24     public override System.Guid GeneratedViewId
25     { get { return new System.Guid("6dda34d85cf14f8d8946e77056f25819"); } }
26 
27     string BuildArticleBreadcumb(ChurchDAL.Section section)
28 #line 10 "C:\Users\Midas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ChurchMVC\ChurchMVC\Views\Shared\_global.spark"
29 {
30 #line hidden
31         using(OutputScope(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
32         {
33 #line default
34 #line 11 "C:\Users\Midas\Documents\Visual Studio 2008    \Projects\ChurchMVC\ChurchMVC\Views\Shared\_global.spark"
35     if (section == null)
36 #line default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **[really](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/use-mvccontrib-fluenthtml-with-spark-view-engine/)** assigned the proper base class, then this exception usually means that you have invalid property in your lambda expression. Double-check it. You actually didn't show nor your spark view nor the code. But, as an example, if you have

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and use

```
this.Hidden(x => x.Name1)
```

you'll get this error (followed by another exception).

Comment: The problem was that while i was setting the basepage type in the web.config, i was adding the assembly in code. Apparently that was overriding/ignoring my web.config settings. I was hoping they were additive, but apparently not.